# getMessageById() slows down

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I am working on a script that works with e-mails and it needs to fetch the timestamp, sender, receiver and subject for an e-mail. The Google script project has several functions in separate script files so I won't be listing everything here, but essentially the main function performs a query and passes it on to a function that fetches data:

```
queriedMessages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(authUsr.mail, {'q':query, 'pageToken':pageToken});
dataOutput_double(sSheet, queriedMessages.messages, queriedMessages.messages.length);
```

So this will send an object to the function ***dataOutput_double*** and the size of the array (if I try to get the size of the array inside the function that outputs data I get an error so that is why this is passed here). The function that outputs the data looks like this:

```
function dataOutput_double(sSheet, messageInfo, aLenght) {
  var sheet = sSheet.getSheets()[0],
      message,
      dataArray = new Array(),
      row = 2;
  var i, dateCheck = new Date;
  dateCheck.setDate(dateCheck.getDate()-1);

  for (i=aLenght-1; i>=0; i--) {
    message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageInfo[i].id);
    if (message.getDate().getDate() == dateCheck.getDate()) {
      sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
      sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(message.getDate());
      sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(message.getFrom());
      sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(message.getTo());
      sheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(message.getSubject());
    }
  }

  return; 
};
```

Some of this code will get removed as there are leftovers from other types of handling this.

The problem as I noticed is that some messages take a long time to get with the getMessageById() method (~ 4 seconds to be exact) and when the script is intended to work with ~1500 mails every day this makes it drag on for quite a while forcing google to stop the script as it takes too long.

Any ideas of how to go around this issue or is this just something that I have to live with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I whipped up:

```
function processEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {maxResults:200, q:"newer_than:1d AND label:INBOX NOT label:PROCESSED"}).messages,

      headers,
      headersFields = ["Date","From","To","Subject"],
      outputValue=[],thisRowValue = [],
      message
  if(messages.length > 0){
    for(var i in messages){
      message = Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', messages[i].id);
     Gmail.Users.Messages.modify( {addLabelIds:["Label_4"]},'me',messages[i].id);
      headers = message.payload.headers
      for(var ii in headers){
        if(headersFields.indexOf(headers[ii].name) != -1){
          thisRowValue.push(headers[ii].value);
        } 
      }           
      outputValue.push(thisRowValue)
      thisRowValue = [];
    }
    var range =  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, ss.getLastColumn()+1, outputValue.length, outputValue[0].length);

    range.setValues(outputValue);
  }


}
```

NOTE: This is intended to run as a trigger. This will batch the trigger call in 200 messages. You will need to add the label PROCESSED to gmail. Also on the line:

```
Gmail.Users.Messages.modify( {addLabelIds:["Label_4"]},'me',messages[i].id);
```

it shows `Label_4`. In my gmail account "PROCESSED" is my 4th custom label.

Comment: I would like to avoid unnecessarily using Gmail API quota to check each message on top of fetching the IDs, but will try that out anyway. Also, your querry has 200 messages in max results but you do not use a page token so you only get at most 100 messages with that script. I also noticed that because of this issue (long getMessageById times) the overal execution time is faster when outputting directly to the spreadsheet rather than using arrays

Comment: Another thing I noticed when trying to implement your idea is that the headers are not consistent. The array ID changes from message to message so you need to make constant checks which is which before outputting the data as they have to be placed in specific columns.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer. While the script itself is not something I can apply, the idea to use the Gmail API to collect messages instead of the GmailApp did help as it managed to slug through 15 pages (1500 e-mails) in 188 seconds. Probably will still have to create a trigger handler just in case to cut off when it gets close to the limit